# how to define output / complete inluigi.contrib.external_program.ExternalProgramTask

Tags: python, python-2.7, dependencies, luigi

I have 2 tasks, each is a subclass of `inluigi.contrib.external_program.ExternalProgramTask`.

Each task is calling a bash script on different dir, and I wanted to add dependency between them:

```
class ATask(ExternalProgramTask):
    def program_args(self):
        return my_script_a.split()

class BTask(ExternalProgramTask):
    def requires(self):
        return ATask()

    def program_args(self):
        return my_script_b.split()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.build([BTask()], workers=2, local_scheduler=False)
```

The error is this:

```
File .../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 182, in run
    raise RuntimeError('Unfulfilled %s at run time: %s' % (deps, ', '.join(missing)))
RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: ATask__...
```

From what I understand - each task is finishing ok by itself (I can see `ATask` finished ok in the visualizer, and BTask is outputing what is expected from a successful run), but the dependecy is somehow messed up.

From what I saw, I need to define an `output` method, and make sure the target will exist, something like adding:

```
def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('foo')
```

to `ATask`, **BUT**, since I can't override `run` in these tasks (because they are `ExternalProgramTask` subclasses), I can't create that file (target). How can I make BTask understand `Atask` had finished ok?

Answer (score 0):

in ATask, add a complete() function which checks if ATask has finished ok (by returning True) or hasn't finished ok (by returning False) and several checks

Comment: and how to do that? Is there a member that is set to True when the task has finished?

Comment: the complete() function gets called by luigi itself to check if a task is already complete. Nothing else.

You can define the complete() function in which you build in checks to make sure the task is complete.

Comment: I tried adding def complete(self): return True, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't follow. How do you propose I'll implement the method? Lets assume the task I'm running is creating a file on the FileSystem. Should I return if the file exists?